# Laser_assembler problem: Published Cloud with 0 points

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Unable to get any point in the cloud. The periodic_snapshotter node gives the message: Published Cloud with 0 points
My aim is to make a point cloud from the tilt_laser topic published by the bag file. (See below)

This is my launch file:

```
<launch>


 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="laser_scan_assembler" output="screen"  name="laser_scan_assembler">
 
   <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="map" />
  </node>

 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="periodic_snapshotter" output="screen" name="periodic_snapshotter" />
 
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 map odom_combined 10"/>

</launch>
```

I am using following bag file from MIT: http://infinity.csail.mit.edu/data/2011/2011-01-24-06-18-27.bag

This is my tf frames: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BBBC11C59055486D!36796&authkey=!AHmnv__kiryoPwE&ithint=file%2cpdf

EDIT===================================
The following is being published by the MIT bag file that I am using:

topics:      /base_odometry/odom                       21032 msgs    : nav_msgs/Odometry
/base_odometry/odometer                     224 msgs    : pr2_mechanism_controllers/Odometer
/base_odometry/state                        224 msgs    : pr2_mechanism_controllers/BaseOdometryState
/base_scan                                 4489 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
/robot_pose_ekf/odom_combined              6333 msgs    : geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped
/tf                                       12687 msgs    : tf/tfMessage
/tilt_scan                                 4489 msgs    : sensor_msgs/LaserScan
/torso_lift_imu/data                      22451 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Imu
/torso_lift_imu/is_calibrated                 1 msg     : std_msgs/Bool
/wide_stereo/left/camera_info_throttle      220 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
/wide_stereo/left/image_rect_throttle       220 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image
/wide_stereo/right/camera_info_throttle     220 msgs    : sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
/wide_stereo/right/image_rect_throttle      220 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236491/laser_assembler-problem:-published-cloud-with-0-points/) by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2016-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It worked finally!!!. The tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans) documentation is little confusing. After reading the tutorial, it feels like the input topic to the laser_assembler is tilt_scan. However, if you see the code in laser_scan_assembler.cpp, it turns out that the subscribed topic is /scan.

After realizing that the required topic is scan and not tilt_scan, I tried to do remapping as follows:

```
    <launch>


 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="laser_scan_assembler" output="screen"  name="laser_scan_assembler">
 <remap from="tilt_scan" to="scan"/>
   <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="map" />
  </node>

 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="periodic_snapshotter" output="screen" name="periodic_snapshotter" />

<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 1 0 0 0 map odom_combined 10"/>

</launch>
```

**However, it still produced 0 point clouds. Finally, running the bag file as rosbag play --clock bagfiles/b.bag /tilt_scan:=/scan helped me get the point clouds**. Don't do remapping inside the launch file. Just do it when you are playing bag file..

Let me know if anyone faces problem in using laser_assembler. Below is the launch file that worked for me using the MIT bag file that I have attached above

```
<launch>


 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="laser_scan_assembler" output="screen"  name="laser_scan_assembler">
    <param name="max_scans" type="int" value="400" />
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="map" />
  </node>

 <node pkg="laser_assembler" type="periodic_snapshotter" output="screen" name="periodic_snapshotter" />
 
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="baselink_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 map odom_combined 10"/>

</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) with karma: 86 on 2016-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Burgos](https://answers.ros.org/users/31448/burgos/) on 2017-08-07**:
What branch of the laser_assembler are you using? I'm trying to follow all the steps you mention, but the periodic snapshotter still says that it is publishing a cloud with 0 points...
I'm in Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic